# Does the placement of your Views in XML have to match your code in your Activity?

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I have an activity that shows some `TextView`s and `EditText`s, as well as `DatePicker`s and `TimePicker`s. Now I am adding a `Spinner`, and its pretty much close to the bottom, just like my code is in the `onCreate()` for it. When I click on the Spinner, it pops open up, probably cuz its close to the bottom and there isn't enough room. So I thought i'd test it out when it was on the top. But it failed. The error is:

```
06-20 15:31:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(980): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zeroe/com.zeroe.AddEventActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to
android.widget.Button
```

I don't understand that, but from what I am guessing, the placement of the XML should follow the placement of the code. I am literally copy-and-pasting the xml code to the top, so I know I am not altering anything. So is this a rule, or am I making some sort of mistake? Thanks for your input in advance.

EDIT:

My Code `Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.reminder_spinner);`

Comment: The order in which views appear is defined by the XML. If you define a view in the XML but never create a java instance of that object it will still appear. You just won't be able to interact with it from within your java code.

Comment: The line of code in your update **cannot** be causing the exception you pasted above.  In the exception you're casting a `Spinner` as a `Button` in the code you are casting a `View` as a `Spinner`.

Comment: I understand that. But moving my Spinner from the bottom to the top makes it crash, but my code is obviously not a Button, which leads me to assume there is some order, or needs to be

Comment: Its probably a copy and paste error then, the order in which you load views in JAVA has **no effect** on how they appear in your activity.

Comment: Well that answers my question. But I don't understand how its a copy and paste error. I copy and paste it in the root, just like the others are in

Comment: @slayton: It happens to be a known _Eclipse/ADT_ issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that when you change your layouts, sometimes *Eclipse* does not rebuild the resources and you are left with *ids* that do not match their XML declared *Views*. A full clean and rebuild should take care of it.

Comment: Interesting. I will try that out. But what if the id has not changed?

Comment: @Andy: Is still the same situation, your resources are out of sync. Seems like if the _aapt_ tool only runs partially, I'm not sure but in either case its a bug in the tools.

Comment: Hmm, your answer seems to make the most sense. For some reason it thinks I am trying to cast a Button into a Spinner. Interesting. And Annoying. How do I do a full clean and rebuild?

Comment: @Andy: _Project > Clean_ and select your project. If _Build automatically_ is enabled then that's enough, otherwise you need to do a _Build_.

Comment: Perfect! It worked just like you said. And I guess I am glad I stumbled upon this weird glitch.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to cast the `Spinner` as a `Button`

I imagine you have some piece of code that looks like this:

```
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.mySpinnerID)
```

Instead it should look like either of these two lines:

```
Spinner mySpinner = findViewById(R.id.mySpinnerID)
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.myButtonID)
```

When creating the java objects that correspond to the views in your .xml you must ensure you are creating the right object type for the corresponding view.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty much self-explanatory. You are trying to cast a `Spinner` object into a `Button` object. Just for confirmation there is no relation between the position of your views in XML and your code accessing that XML.